# Javascript Arrow function with ternary

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions, ternary

So being new to arrow functions I know this is a ID10T error but I am stuck with implementing my ternary.

To start I had no issues getting my formula figured out and this works.

```
const nVal = 138
const nValue = Math.floor(nVal/100)+Math.floor(nVal%100/10)+nVal%10
```

The problem comes in when I try to implement the ternary with the arrow function: I am getting a NaN as a return

```
const nVal = 138
const nValue = nVal => nVal == 11 || nVal == 22 ||nVal == 33 ? nVal = nVal : nVal = Math.floor(nVal/100)+Math.floor(nVal%100/10)+nVal%10
```

Comment: What is the problem exactly?

Comment: Also, why even use a conditional operator when it clearly doesn't fit your need?

Comment: When you assign `nVal` in `nValue` function, it will just change the value of `nVal` parameter. Not the variable.

Comment: Is this part intentional? `? nVal = nVal :`

Comment: `const nValue = nVal => [return value]` therefore `nVal => (nVal == 11 || nVal == 22 || nVal == 33) ? nVal : Math.floor(nVal/100)+Math.floor(nVal%100/10)+nVal%10` (you had two assignments - `nVal=...` - instead of two values)

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález seems like it's there to satisfy the conditional operator. A bit of a "when you have a hammer everything looks like a nail" problem.

Comment: Thanks guys. Just getting back into things and trying to focus on using some of the newer javascript features and well I made it more complex than it needed to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```js
const nVal = 138;
const nValue = nVal === 11 || nVal === 22 ||nVal === 33 ? nVal : Math.floor(nVal/100)+Math.floor(nVal%100/10)+nVal%10;

console.log(nValue);
```

Comment: Thank you. I am just getting back into javascript after almost a decade and I guess I am just missing something with some of the new operators. More work to be done:)

Comment: @Russ Glad to help. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you rather expect something like this:

```js
const nValue = nVal => nVal == 11 || nVal == 22 ||nVal == 33 ? nVal : Math.floor(nVal/100)+Math.floor(nVal%100/10)+nVal%10;
```